# Avoid nesting promises

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I'm getting an "Avoid nesting promises" (for jslint) for the following function. How can I write this without nesting promises?

```
function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
  return retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey)
    .then(uids => {
      let diff = uids.diff(users_uids)
      let deletes = []
      diff.forEach(key => {
        deletes.push(firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove())
      })
      return Promise.all(deletes)
        .then(value => {
          return diff
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: It appears that the JSLint is just making a wrong suggestion and is trying to force you to write less clear code.  `.map()` would be better here than `.forEach()`, but that probably won't change what JSLint thinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last `then` can be moved up to the main chain by returning the `Promise.all` result:

```
function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
  let diff;
  return retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey)
    .then(uids => {
      diff = uids.diff(users_uids)
      let deletes = []
      diff.forEach(key => {
        deletes.push(firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove())
      })
      return Promise.all(deletes)
    })
    .then(value => {
      return diff
    })
}
```

Note that for this to work, the scope of the variable `diff` needs to be enlarged, as done above. Alternatively you could add `diff` to the arguments passed to `Promise.all`, so you get access to `diff` as a promised value:

```
function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
  return retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey)
    .then(uids => {
      let diff = uids.diff(users_uids)
      let deletes = []
      diff.forEach(key => {
        deletes.push(firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove())
      })
      return Promise.all([diff, ...deletes])
    })
    .then(([diff]) => {
      return diff
    })
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but you could use `map` instead of `forEach` with `push`:

```
  let deletes = diff.map(key => {
    return firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I did not see this myself :( great suggestion also regarding the map. Is this more performant then a foreach ?

Comment: It should not make much of a difference in performance (try it), but it looks a bit cleaner and fits with a *functional programming* style.

Comment: can't see much performance difference but indeed it looks better!

Comment: Your first suggestion is NOT cleaner code that the OP's original code.  Putting the variable `diff` in a higher scope just for this purpose is downright ugly.  `.map()` seems like the right option or even better, use Bluebird's `Promise.map()` which combines `.map()` and `Promise.all()`.  Now that I see what you're doing with the second one, I don't consider that to be simpler code to understand than the OP's original code either.  Making a JSLint happy should not result in more obtuse code.  Sometimes the JSLint is just wrong and a simple comment pragma will get it to shut up.

Answer (score 0):

I this case, I think jsLint is just steering you wrong into more complicated code.  Sometimes, you get that from a linter and the best option in that case is to bypass the linter for a specific line of code or function or a specific linter rule.

This is the simplest and clearest implementation of your code I can think of (which should be your priority):

```
function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
    return retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey).then(uids => {
        const diff = uids.diff(users_uids);
        // wait for all deletes to be done, then return diff
        return Promise.all(diff.map(key => {
            return firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove();
        })).then(() => diff);
    });
}
```

Or, using Bluebird's `.map()`, you can do this:

```
// using Bluebird's Promise.map()
function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
    return retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey).then(uids => {
        const diff = uids.diff(users_uids);
        // wait for all deletes to be done, then return diff
        return Promise.map(diff, key => {
            return firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove();
        }).then(() => diff);
    });
}
```

Or, using async/await:

```
async function deleteUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey, users_uids) {
    const uids = await retrieveUIDsFromDBForKey(rootkey);
    const diff = uids.diff(users_uids);
    await Promise.all(diff.map(key => {
        return firebase.database().ref(rootkey + "/" + key).remove();
    }));
    return diff;
}
```

I don't have an ES7-capable jsLint installed, but the last option should avoid the nesting warning.  The first two, probably not, but trying to avoid that warning will just make worse code so IMO, you should just disable the warning.